# fullcalendar: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use fullcalendar and it keeps throwing this error. I have all the required files included which are:

```
fullcalendar.js
fullcalendar.css
moment.js
```

However I'm getting this following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeData' of undefined
    at getMomentLocaleData (fullcalendar.js:2554)
    at locale (fullcalendar.js:2445)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (fullcalendar.js:2559)
    at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (fullcalendar.js:12499)
    at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (fullcalendar.js:7367)
    at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (fullcalendar.js:12109)
    at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:30)
```

Here is my initialization of  fullcalendar:

```
window.onload = function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        handleWindowResize: true,
        defaultView: 'month',
        themeSystem: "bootstrap3",
        eventLimit: true,
        //navLinks: true, // enable clicking on different days
        week: true,
        day: true,
        agenda: true,
        basic: true,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'event1',
                start: '2017-11-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Holiday',
                start: '2017-11-05',
                end: '2017-11-07'
            },
            {
                title: 'event3',
                start: '2017-11-09T12:30:00',
                allDay: false // will make the time show
            }
        ]
    })

    $(".fc-today-button").html('<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>');
    $(".fc-prev-button").html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>');
    $(".fc-next-button").html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>');
}
```

The calendar displays fine but because of this error, any jQuery that needs to be ran after is not running because of this exception.

Any pointers?

Comment: "all the required files, which are". Well you missed out jQuery from that list, for a start. Also, jquery and momentJS must be loaded _before_ fullcalendar.js. You haven't shown explicitly in your sample the order of loading, but just going on the list you provided it appears momentJS may be being added after fullCalendar? The fact the stack trace shows the error is in a function called "getMomentLocaleData" adds weight to this theory, I think. Follow the guidance at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/ carefully to set up your page properly.

Comment: @ADyson I didn't realise that I wasn't importing `moment` before `fullcalendar` now it seems to work. Thanks.